# Обновление списка в цикле

Tags: c#, list

Здравствуйте, вот мой участок кода:

```
foreach(var process in Processes)
        {
            int SpendTime = QuantOfTime;
            foreach(var potok in process.Potoks)
            {
                if(potok.TimeOfOnePotok <= SpendTime)
                {
                    potok.Start();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Поток №{potok.Id} {potok.Message}");
                    SpendTime -= potok.TimeOfOnePotok;
                    process.Potoks.Remove(potok);
                }
                else
                {
                    potok.Start(SpendTime);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Поток №{potok.Id} {potok.Message}");
                    Processes.Add(process);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Выдает ошибку, что невозможно менять коллекцию через цикл. На что лучше заменить цикл или что лучше использовать в подобных случаях?

Comment: А какой смысл? Вы хотите смоделировать очередь? Зачем добавлять элемент, который там уже есть?

Comment: Это классика, через цикл `foreach` пытаться изменять  содержимое коллекции невозможно. Хотите поиграться - используйте `for`.

Comment: Смысл выполнения цикла: пока все элементы не станут валидными, они будут добавляться в список, иначе он удаляется . 
Элемент добавляется видоизмененный, и он должен вызваться после прохождения всех начальных элементов списка. В итоге должен был получиться циклический алгоритм прогнозирования в ОС, показывающий работу с процессами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменение итерируемой коллекции в цикле `foreach` может приводить к аномалиям, например к бессконечным циклам.

Если вы хотите что-то менять, то итерируйте руками в цикле `for`.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вы моделируете очередь. Для этого удобнее использовать очередь, как ни странно. Ваш код будет при этом таким:

```
Queue<Process> Processes;

while (Processes.Count > 0)
{
    var process = Processes.Dequeue();
    if (...)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        ...
        Processes.Enqueue(process);
    }
}
```

Мой код, в отличие от вашего, удаляет текущий элемент из очереди, но, думаю, вам именно это и нужно.